# How to send variable value using php in header?

Tags: php

I am trying to send user_id in url which id i get after login conform.Following are the code
 extract($_POST);

```
    $result = $dbg->prepare("SELECT `p_id`,`email` FROM `complit_register_provider` WHERE `email`=:hjhjhjh AND `password`=:psspsps") ;
                      $result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $login_mail);
                      $result->bindParam(':psspsps', $login_password);
                      $result->execute();
                      $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                      $row=$result->rowCount();
             if($rows){
                 $result=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                 $_SESSION['Uname']=$rows['email'];
                 $_SESSION['Utype']="provider";
                $_SESSION['Uid']=$rows['p_id'];
        $user_id=$_SESSION['Uid'];

header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=$user_id');
             }
```

But it's not working. The url showing like.

http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=$user_id,
It should show for example like
http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=9
How can i do this?

Comment: seriously dont you see that single quote ? php dont parse variable in single quote http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything inside single quotes, `''`, is treated as a string by php.

Change it to 
`header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show='. $user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show='.$user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=$user_id");
```

instead of

```
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=$user_id');
```

For more information about the difference between single quotes and double quotes you should have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else have pointed out, you are using single quotes `''` which causes PHP to not recognize the `$user_id` variable you are trying to send.

Use double quotes `""` to solve this problem.

```
header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/pages/user_index/provider/user_profile/show_own_profile.php?Show=$user_id");
```

Further reading on differences between the two types of quotes in PHP:

> [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)